# Null checking not working

Tags: java, android

sorry if this is a low quality question, but still is a question :) here im using a simple in the eyes condition for checking EditText's null Being,

```
public String theuser=null;
public String thepass=null;

EditText  u=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputuser);
this.theuser = u.getText().toString();
EditText p =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputpassword);
this.thepass = p.getText().toString();

if ((theuser.equals(null))||(thepass.equals(null))){ 
    Toast.makeText(this,"Username and Password Cant Be Empty!",     
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
}else{
    Log.i("lifemate","did you click me ?!"+theuser+"  "+thepass);
    BusProvider.getInstance().post(SendRequestInfo());
}
```

but the null check seems to be not working ! i tried .equals(null)  and .equals("") too still not working! do guys know why is that ?!

Comment: What do you mean by "seems not to be working"? (Hint: use `==` instead to check for nullity - or `.equals("")` to check for an empty string...) And *please* format your code more readably...

Comment: and btw, `""` and `null` are not the same

Comment: @Jon Skeet...You should put it as answer to get the points :)

Comment: use TextUtils.isEmpty. It does check for empty strings and null values

Comment: :) :)  awesome...is it possible that HE IS stackoverflow? :)...never seen so many points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Equals contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) states that:

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

But when `x` is `null` this would cause a [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) because you are trying to access a method of a `null` object.

In short use `x == null` rather than `x.equals(null)`.

**But in your case**

You are testing the text value from a `TextView`. I would not expect this to be `null`, particulary as you call `toString()` on a `CharSequence`. So this will be just empty if anything, i.e. you can do this:

```
if ("".equals(theuser) || "".equals(thepass)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparison to `null` should be done using the `==` operator.

So use `if (theuser==null || thepass == null)`.

Comment: i forgot to write this is first that i have done :D but didnt work yet

Answer (score 2):

that 
 `if ((theuser.equals(null))||(thepass.equals(null))){`

must be 
`if ((theuser.equals(""))||(thepassequals(""))){`

because `getText()` returns an empty string if there is no input. It not return null.

Answer (score 0):

equals null is not applicable for the reference of your String object.

You need to use `(mystring != null)` to test the nullability.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if ((theuser.equals(null))||(thepass.equals(null)))
```

with

```
if (theuser==null||thepass==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking the null in string android provide very good class over there

you just pass your string in

```
//check while for the null string. 
if(TextUtils.isEmpty("YOUR_STRING")){
 //perform operation. 
}
```

It will automatically handle NULL as well as EMPTY string.